# need some help for a image slide show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

On my first day of work with html I built a navigation bar yesterday which looks pretty sweet to me ...take a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunu0000/JhVsn/)

Now I want to include a slideshow like thing in my site next probably using some javascript or jquery plug ins...I am looking for something similar to the one at [www.forward.co.uk/](http://www.forward.co.uk/) (the text on the image looks a pretty good to me)

I have searched on github too ..but the results i got did not match the style i want ..probably my keywords for the search were not too precise..

Comment: you mean the underline ?

Comment: no no..the transparent band with text which appears on the images

Comment: Nivo slider is pretty well known / documented? Easy to set up and deploy also nivo.dev7studios.com

Comment: @timothyclifford thanks nivo slider looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/JhVsn/1/

or this ( only for text)

http://jsfiddle.net/JhVsn/2/

Comment: well thanks for the effects..but i think you misunderstood me..i want a image slide show tool.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#panel1-2

Comment: yup that's the sort of thing i am looking for..thanks :)

Comment: yup i know :) ..i just a bit too excited, so i forgot..anyways accepted the answer and the good news is i just finished building a slideshow with those same bands of text \m/